# For a normal random variable, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $F(-\sqrt{y}) = 1 - F(\sqrt{y})$?

Tags: probability

For a normal random variable, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $F(-\sqrt{y}) = 1 - F(\sqrt{y})$?

[image]

[image]

How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Two colored areas are of the same size. The PDF is N(0,1)]

Intuitive explanation. The probability density function drawn is $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Look at the two colored areas. Their areas are equal. The white region corresponds to $P(-\sqrt{y}<X<\sqrt{y})$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$
1-\Phi(\sqrt{y})=1-P(X\leq\sqrt{y})=P(X>\sqrt{y})=P(X\geq\sqrt{y}),
$$
since $P(X=\sqrt{y})=0$. The short answer, at this point, is symmetry: the standard normal distribution is symmetry about $x=0$, so that 
$$
P(X\geq\sqrt{y})=P(X\leq-\sqrt{y})=\Phi(-\sqrt{y}).
$$
The long answer:
$$
P(X\geq\sqrt{y})=\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx;
$$
the substitution $w=-x$, $dw=-dx$ then yields
$$
\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx=-\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\infty}\frac{e^{-w^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dw=\int_{-\infty}^{-\sqrt{y}}\frac{e^{-w^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dw=P(X\leq-\sqrt{y}).
$$
Graphically: here is a graph of the density function:

[image: Density Function]

And here is the CDF, $\Phi$:

[image: CDF]

Comment: I think I am lost at the part $P(X>\sqrt{y})=P(X<-\sqrt{y})$. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/pm8J2mZ.png) If the blue shaded part of the image linked is $P(X>\sqrt{y})$ then the rest should be $P(X<\sqrt{y})$, how is it $P(X<-\sqrt{y})$

Comment: @JiewMeng The green section your arrow pointing towards is $Pr(X<\sqrt{y})$. Notice that if you draw the line $x=-\sqrt{y}$, you discover that the area left of it equals the area right of $x=\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @FrenzYDT. yes but thats what I understand it to be $1-P(\sqrt{y})$? Which is supposed to equals $P(-\sqrt{y})$? The later statement I don't understand ... why is $P(X>\sqrt{y})=P(X<-\sqrt{y})$

Comment: @JiewMeng I've updated some; see if it makes more sense to you now.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson, yes it mathematically makes sense now ... but it will be nice to have a graphical view ... I can visualize how $P(X>\sqrt{y})=P(X<-\sqrt{y})$ like in the image I linked in my 1st comment ... it will be nice if u could draw a graph how that might make sense in paint or something, then print screen? But thank you for your explaination so far

Comment: @JiewMeng I added a couple of pictures, one of the PDF and one of the CDF.